# What method of NSURLConnection's delegate is called if connection close?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I create a `NSURLConnection` to download a file from server, the downloaded file is generated on the fly so server will set the data size to somewhat bigger than actual size, the server closes the download session when all the generated data is sent.

My question is that will `NSURLConnection` delegate method `connectionDidFinishLoading` be invoked in this case? If not, what delegate methods will be called?

Comment: Either that or [`connection:didFailWithError:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:didFailWithError:). You should code for both.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does the server lie about the Content-Length? Content-Length is optional in a response. If a server doesn't know the Content-Length up front it can leave that header off. As you've stated, the server can signal the completion of the response by closing the connection.

Comment: @JefferyThomas you're right, the Content-Length seem to be useless here. I didn't know that it is optional.